# Pasting emojis  in Vim or Neovim

Tags: vimrc, neovim

Been to trying to figure out why pasting an emoji from the clipboard doesn't paste properly when using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> on macOS.

I have the following key bindings in my `.vimrc`

```
vnoremap <M-c> "+y
nnoremap <M-v> "+p
inoremap <M-v> <esc>"+p
```

Is there any way to get a list of escape sequences so I can hopefully get the proper emoji to paste.

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was totally an issue with iTerm2 and not mapping <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to `^[v` within the iTerm2 settings.

Comment: how did you solve it?